# How to config system.js when using angular2?

Tags: angular, es6-promise, systemjs

We are making a little sample with angular 2, I copied the code from the quickstart example, there is an error: "es6Promise is undefined".

We found that the https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js is not the pure system.js, it include the following customized code:

```js
document.write('
<script type="text/javascript" src="'+basePath+'es6-module-loader@0.16.6.js" data-init="upgradeSystemLoader"></script>')

System.config({
  paths:{
    "*":"https://registry.jspm.io/*.js",
    "~/*":"*.js",
    "npm:*":"https://npm.jspm.io/*.js",
    "github:*":"https://github.jspm.io/*.js"
  },
  map:{
    traceur:"github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur@0.0.87",
    "traceur-runtime":"github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87",
    babel:"npm:babel-core@5"
  }
});
```

We want to load this file locally, anyone knows how to config it? How to generate the system@0.16.js (combined system.js and customized configuration)?

Comment: check this starting project https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play for a running ES6 / SystemJs / Angular 2 seed, maintained by an Angular 2 team member

Comment: Hi jhadesdev, thanks for your comment. I opened the link, in index.html under src folder, it referenced libraries under lib folder, do you know where I can got a working project?

Comment: If you clone the repo or download as zip, then npm install, then gulp play it should open a browser with a working page

Answer (score 0):

You can configure SystemJS in a script tag, for instance in index.html:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    baseURL: '<%= APP_BASE %>',
    paths: {'*': '*.js?v=<%= VERSION %>'},
    defaultJSExtensions: true
  });

</script>
```

I use the following versions

```
"angular2": "=2.0.0-alpha.37",
"es6-module-loader": "^0.16.6",
"systemjs": "^0.18.10",
"zone.js": "^0.5.4",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.1"
```

Comment: Hi cghislai, thanks for you answer. We know how to config the system in index.html. We used the pure system.js and config it in html,  and got the error: es6Promise is undefined. Do you know how to fix it? we want to know how is the system@0.16.js coming.